# How to check number of complete trip occurances per route

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have table with multiple points per route. I want to retrieve the number of complete trips occured per route. Marker 1 -> 5 makes one trip.

Any suggestion will be greatly appreciated.

[image]

Comment: I'd check out `GROUP BY` and `COUNT()`.

Comment: Can you guarantee that id is always in order?  If not, how are you grouping the rows into individual trips?  Also, do trips always start at Marker 1 and continue to Marker 5?

Comment: @shanmugam The logic of this is tied to the order in which markers are added? What happens if someone adds 1 and 2 (but didn't complete 3, 4 , 5) and then someone adds 3, 4 and 5 (they didn't complete 1, 2)? How can you tell if that is a full run or two partial runs?

Answer (score 0):

If a trip starts always from marker 1 and step throug markers, but it can stops before reaching the final marker, you can use this:

```
select routeid, count(marker) trip_n
from RouteTable 
where marker=5
group by routeid
```

If markers "touched" by a trip are completely random, but you need to count how many complete you have, use this:

```
;with
g as (select distinct routeid from RouteTable ),
n as (select 1 n union all select 2 union all select 3 union all select 4 union all select 5 ),
c as (
    select routeid, marker, count(marker) cnt
    from RouteTable 
    group by routeid, marker
),
s as (
    select g.*, n marker, isnull(cnt,0) cnt
    from g
    cross join n
    left join c on c.marker = n.n
)
select routeid, /*count(distinct marker) n_mark, */min(cnt) n_trip
from s
group by routeid
```

Comment: ok, you mean that if the marker is 1->4 is not complete and you dont want to count it? can you have gaps? 1,3,5 without 2 and 4 is possible?

Comment: thank you for your suggestion. iam looking for complete trips, there should not be any missing markers in the route. And as per your answer if trips happened like this  2->5,3->5,1->5, trips count is wrong.

Answer (score 0):

```
select distinct m1.routeid, isnull(m2.[Trips],0)
from [TableName] m1
left join
(SELECT routeid, count(*) / 5 as [Trips]
  FROM [Tablename] m
  where 5 = (select count(distinct marker) 
  from [TableName]
  where routeid=m.routeid)
  group by routeid) m2
  on m1.routeid=m2.routeid
```

Added for dynamic number of markers from a [Marker] table:

```
select distinct m1.routeid, isnull(m2.[Trips],0)
from [TableName] m1
left join
(SELECT routeid, count(*) / 5 as [Trips]
  FROM [Tablename] m
  where (select [no_of_markers] from [Markers] where [route_id]=m.route_id) = (select count(distinct marker) 
  from [TableName]
  where routeid=m.routeid)
  group by routeid) m2
  on m1.routeid=m2.routeid
```

Comment: @shanmugam By my reasoning there would have to be other tables to hold marker/route info, but there is no mention, so they must be fixed as having 5 markers.

Comment: no.of markers in the trip should not be fixed, there should not be any missing markers in the trip, trip should start from 1 and ends with last marker which may vary from route to route

Comment: @shanmugam Where is the data that says how many markers are in each trip? If a route has markers 1-4 how do we know the last marker isn't 5 or 6?

Comment: @cloudsafe: route is dynamic. i didnt mention that table here. I mentioned only routeid. if route having 5 markers then 5 is the last marker. Else In other way i want the trip as 1->1 that means trip starts from 1 and end with 1 and continues for next trip

Comment: @shanmugam I have added an addition to the script to include dynamic route_ids

Comment: please try your answer with this data.. it simply does not work! `select * from (values (1,1,1),(2,2,1),(3,1,1),(4,1,1),(5,2,1),(6,3,1),(7,1,1),(8,2,1),(9,3,1),(10,4,1),(11, 5,1)) [TableName] (id, marker, routeid)`

Comment: @MtwStark From the updates yesterday, it won't work with the expanded description. My code assumed that one route had to be finished before the next would start, like in the data provided in the question.